# Stick chathead to edges and corners

Tags: android, android-windowmanager

I'm developing a chat head application using the windowManager and override TouchListener and it contains a function where user should select a position(corners and edges) on screen that will be used to pin the chat head.when user releases the view when dragging ,it should find the closest position(corners and edges) and stick to it  The thing is, the view doesn't place in the right position even though the values are correct(x and y). These are the steps I have done so far.

1. I divided the screen into four equal parts.
2. When the view gets into any of these parts, i could find the closest position and then i use,

`params.x ,params.y and Params.gravity` and set the position with `mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(view, params);`

but the position that the view is updated with is wrong , but the log shows correct x and y values, what could be the problem though ? is there any alternate ways to do this ? How can i animate this instead of using updateViewLayout ?

Comment: I think you just have to set "params.gravity" to match the closest edge and then set only the OTHER coordinate. I mean: the most top-left quarter of screen uses "gravity = left | top" and you can use standards X, Y. The most top-right quarter of screen uses "gravity = top | right" where Y is the default value, but X is the distance from the RIGHT edge. The quarter bottom-left uses "gravity = bottom | left" and uses standard X but the Y is the distance from the bottom. The last quarter uses "gravity = bottom | right" and uses X and Y as the distance from the bottom-right corner

Comment: I already did that , it doesn't work !